# how to sum until obtain one given value considering conditions on other columns using excel?

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have this table:

[image]

```
    measure Retrofit cost   Savings PER MONTH
1   1000    400
2   1300    207
3   1500    232
4   1100    215
5   1000    241
6   1500    277
7   1000    354
8   900 364
9   1500    427
10  1000    440
11  1300    201
12  2000    460
13  1000    373
14  1300    272
15  1500    250
16  3000    314
17  1300    390
18  1000    490
```

how to sum "Retrofit Cost" values until reach a given value - let's say 6000 - considering the highest "savings per month" values. So this would be:

measure 18+measure12+measure10+measure9=5500.

if we sum the next higher savings value would go over 6000.

Comment: So you're summing them at random? Or are you trying to get the closest value to <6000?

Comment: I considered the measures with the higher savings until obtain 6000 (in this case is less since the next measure implies passing 6000)

Comment: Lets say row 3 retrofit cost is 200 instead of 1500, should it be then m18+m12+m10+m9+m2 = 5700 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=TAKE(SCAN(0,TAKE(SORT(B1:C18,2,-1),,1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF((a+b)<=6000,a+b,a))),-1,1)
```

[image]